# Run vim without loading .vimrc but loading plugins

Tags: vim

I'm running `gvim -u NONE` to open gvim without using `.vimrc`, but in the same time I would like to be able to call the commands from the plugins inside the plugin/ folder.

I tried it running `:filetype plugin` on but it doesn't work..

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use `-u NORC` instead of `-u NONE`. See `:help --noplugin`.

Comment: sorry but for me it doesn't work..I have run `:FufFile` or `:TagbarToggle` and it says command not found.. I don't get that error if I run them after running gvim plain.

Comment: `:scriptnames` will tell you which plugins have been sourced. You may also need to pass `-N` to `:set nocompatible`; some plugins check for that.